# Media Player error when playing Video in Emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to play video from youtube using this code but I get this error from my log cat:

```
06-28 16:23:09.794: E/MediaPlayer(621): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class PromoActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.frux.kfcmobile.R.layout.promo);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(com.frux.kfcmobile.R.id.videoView);
    String path = "rtsp://v4.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQmofK96HM6gyhMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBWluZGV4YJWAl-O04anmTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp";
    Uri vid = Uri.parse(path);
    videoView.setVideoURI(vid);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.start();
    videoView.requestFocus();
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: may be try to set media controller first before video uri it should work.

Comment: i just moved the controller before the Uri but I still got the error

Comment: can u try to play any file through the sd card, if it plays then might be streaming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    video.setVideoURI(Uri
                    .parse("rtsp://v6.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk-fYZWNAPDsxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"));
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.start();
```

And you try to run in Device.. Because in emulator only some videos will get played.

Comment: yeah it works in device even its not working in emulator. thanks